# What logic dictates the order answers show up in?

Tags: support, answers

Assume a question has four answers. One has 0 upvotes, the other three all have 1. Is there any logic to which will show at the top of the page if you refresh?

From testing it looks like the 0 will always be at the bottom, but the 1's change in order.

I assume there's some kind of logic here but I'm really curious what it is. My best guess is they rotate to give equal "above the fold" page time, but I welcome more educated answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default, answers are sorted in vote order, with tied answers being sorted randomly each time the page is loaded.

You can change the sort order using the "order by" control on any page. You can sort by votes (the default), age, or latest activity. (As an active editor I long ago changed my sort order to latest activity; I find this still most useful as a mod.)

The exception is that accepted answers are pinned to the top regardless of their vote score or the sort method chosen. (Unless it's an accepted self-answer — in that case they aren't pinned and are sorted as if they didn't have the acceptance checkmark.)